# Как взять только нужную информацию с сайта

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

Есть сайт, с которого мне нужно взять блок новостей и вывести их в ListView. Почитал, что лучше это делать с помощью HtmlAgilityPack.

```
page = new HtmlDocument();
        page.LoadHtml(address);
        IEnumerable<HtmlNode> news = page.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("class") && d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("news"));
```

И дальше не знаю что сделать.

Вот сам код из сайта.

```html
<ul class="news"> 

<li class="dotes">

         <div class="nimg"><a href="http://radio.aplus.by/news/1394-festivalnyj-sezon-k-pop-kultury-hallyu.html"><img src="http://radio.aplus.by/uploads/news/thumbs/1470812232_afisha.jpg" alt=""></a><span class="ramka">&nbsp;</span></div>
         <div class="ntext"><span class="date">10.08.2016</span>
           <a href="http://radio.aplus.by/news/1394-festivalnyj-sezon-k-pop-kultury-hallyu.html" class="ntitle">Фестивальный сезон... 
           <a href="http://radio.aplus.by/news/1394-festivalnyj-sezon-k-pop-kultury-hallyu.html#comments" class="comments">Комментарии (0)</a></div>
        
        <div class="clrr"></div>
         </li>
  ........................... и так далее...................
  </ul>
```

Я так понял для начала нужно взять сам класс news, потом для каждого dotes (их вроде всегда 10) нужно брать классы внутри него и потом брать из них информацию. Как выводить такие данные в Listiew я знаю. Но как взять данные из этих классов, пока не могу разобраться.

Мне бы немного понять принцип всего этого или какие-нибудь хорошие примеры работы с Html Agility Pack.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал использовать какой нибудь сервис, типа import.io. Там можно настроить парсинг любого сайта и получать нужные данные по удобному REST-API.

Comment: Нет, такое мне не подойдет. Приложение для магазина Windows идет и зависеть о сервиса не хочется.

Comment: Тогда быть может сам сайт предоставляет API для получения новостей? Или RSS.

Comment: В общем всё получилось. Только одна проблема осталась.
В теге <div ... </div> есть свои теги и после них идёт текст, который никакими тегами не выделен, то есть задан неявно. Как его получить? Chrome показывает, что это объект (text), но его получить в коде не получается.

Comment: Попробуй что нибудь типа `.InnerText`